# How to prove $D_x^k(x^k)=k!$ using mathematical induction?

Tags: calculus, induction

How to prove $D_x^k(x^k)=k!$?

Well, I know first I have to prove $D_x^1(x^1)=1!$ which is easy to prove, then I will prove

Assume  $$D_x^k(x^k)=k!$$

Show:  $$D_x^{k+1}(x^{k+1})=(k+1)!$$

Which I stuck on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
D_x^{k+1} x^{k+1} &= D_x^k D_x^1 x^{k+1} \\
&= (k+1) D_x^k x^k
\end{align}
$$

I think you got the rest